# what does this method do?

Tags: javascript, css, forms

script :

```
window.onload = initForms;

function initForms() {
for (var i=0; i< document.forms.length; i++) {
    document.forms[i].onsubmit = function() {return validForm();}
}
}

function validForm() {
var allGood = true;
var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) {
    if (!validTag(allTags[i])) {
        allGood = false;
    }
}
return allGood;

function validTag(thisTag) {
    var outClass = "";
    var allClasses = thisTag.className.split(" ");

    for (var j=0; j<allClasses.length; j++) {
        outClass += validBasedOnClass(allClasses[j]) + " ";
    }

    thisTag.className = outClass;

    if (outClass.indexOf("invalid") > -1) {
        thisTag.focus();
        if (thisTag.nodeName == "INPUT") {
            thisTag.select();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

    function validBasedOnClass(thisClass) {
        var classBack = "";

        switch(thisClass) {
            case "":
            case "invalid":
                break;
            case "reqd":
                if (allGood && thisTag.value == "") {
                    classBack = "invalid ";
                }
                classBack += thisClass;
                break;
            default:
                classBack += thisClass;
        }
        return classBack;
    }
}
}
```

This code is meant to check if the user entered the required fields in the HTML form.If the user leaves the required field the field is marked with color.

In the above code what does the `function validTag(thisTag)` is do ? What is the identifier ***invalid*** ? This is not declared anywhere in the HTML file.In case here is the HTML file :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Car Picker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Car Picker</h2>
<form action="#">
<p>
    <label for="emailAddr">Enter your email address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input id="emailAddr" type="text" size="30" class="reqd email" />
    </label></br />
    <label for="emailAddr2">Re-enter your email address:<input id="emailAddr2" type="text" size="30" class="reqd emailAddr" />
    </label>
</p>
<p><label for="color">Colors:
    <select id="color" class="reqd">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</label></p>
<p>Options:
    <label for="sunroof"><input type="checkbox" id="sunroof" value="Yes" />Sunroof (Two door only)</label>
    <label for="pWindows"><input type="checkbox" id="pWindows" value="Yes" />Power Windows</label>
</p>
<p><label for="DoorCt">Doors:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" id="twoDoor" name="DoorCt" value="twoDoor" class="radio" />Two
    <input type="radio" id="fourDoor" name="DoorCt" value="fourDoor" class="radio" />Four
</label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The css file :

```
body {
color: #000;
background-color: #FFF;
}

input.invalid {
background-color: #FF9;
border: 2px red inset;
}

label.invalid {
color: #F00;
font-weight: bold;
}

select {
margin-left: 80px;
}

input {
margin-left: 30px;
}

input+select, input+input {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `invalid` class is added via javascript when a user has submitted the form and one of the fields is invalid?

Comment: @MrMisterMan The class is added in the javascript he posted.

Comment: Get the answer from the person who wrote this part of the script

Comment: @ AmGates i don't think she will answer me!

Comment: Can't imagine why not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `reqd` class is set, the `validBasedOnClass` function returns the class name `invalid` if the specified control is empty. In this case, that class is added to the control.
If the class `invalid` is added, the control gets the focus too.

So it's basically a form validator that ensures that all inputs with the class `reqd` should be filled before the form is posted.

But where did you get this code from, if you apparently don't know what it does? It seems quite unstructured code too. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: the class is declared in the css file

Comment: @ GolezTrol can you please elaborate what is happening. I am messed up , as soon as the function `validTag` is called.

Comment: I think I did. But ok. If `validTag` splits the class of the element to get all separate classes. It calls `validBasedOnClass` for each class of that element. If the class is `reqd`, it checks if the value is empty. If so, it returns a string containing `invalid`, which is then set in the element. So all empty inputs get this invalid class, if they had the class `reqd`. But as you say, you get messed up, and so did I. This code is messy and unstructured. There are better alternatives, like the JQuery library I mentioned.

Comment: @ GolezTrol while going through the tutorials from [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com)

Comment: In case you wondered, `thisTag.className` actually gets the attibute `class` of thisTag. `class` is a reserved word, that's why the attribute is called `className` in JavaScript.

Comment: @ GolezTrol if the class is `reqd` and the value is empty why the code is sending `classBack += thisClass;` what does it do ?

Comment: classBack is the class that is returned from the function. $thisClass is the parameter of the function. That class is added to the result to make sure that it remains existing. So after this check, an element has the class `reqd` and `invalid`.

Comment: and what is the need to dynamically change the tag using the statement `thisTag.className = outClass;` in the function `validTag()`

Answer (score 1):

- In the above code what does the function validTag(thisTag) is do ?

The `validTag` function is checking if all the `reqd` tags are valid (a tag is invalid if he is empty).

- What is the identifier invalid ?

Invalid is not an identifier, it's a class name set in the `validBasedOnClass` function (it's set if the tag is not valid). (the line that sets it is : `classBack = "invalid ";`)

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments carefully.

```
function validTag(thisTag) {
    var outClass = "";
    var allClasses = thisTag.className.split(" ");
    /* <Array> allClasses = a list of all separate class names of `thisTag`*/

    /* This loop walks through all elements of the `allClasses` array, and
     * calls the `validBasedOnClasses` function (defined below). The return
     * value of the function is added to `outClass`, together with a space " "*/
    for (var j=0; j<allClasses.length; j++) {
        outClass += validBasedOnClass(allClasses[j]) + " ";
    }
    /*The class attribute of the element is set to the string `outClass`*/
    thisTag.className = outClass;

    /*Can the string "invalid" be found in the `outClass` string? */
    if (outClass.indexOf("invalid") > -1) {
        thisTag.focus();/* Puts the user focus to the element*/
        if (thisTag.nodeName == "INPUT") {
            /* Selects everything in the input, so that the user can easily
             * overwrite the contents of the input field*/
            thisTag.select();
        }
        return false; /*Invalid, return FALSE*/
    }
    return true; /*Valid, return TRUE*/

    /* <function> validBasedOnClass - a function used above
     * This function accepts a parameter, which equals one of the class names
     *  of the element */
    function validBasedOnClass(thisClass) {
        var classBack = ""; /* <string> classBack. This string will be returned*/

        switch(thisClass) {
            case "": /* An empty class name - Nothing to check*/
            case "invalid": /* "invalid" - Remove this class, so that the 
                             * code can validate again (when the "reqd" class
                             * is encountered) */
                break;
            case "reqd": /* class name == "reqd" */

                /* <boolean> `allGood` is defined at the main function.
                 * This function will only mark the FIRST invalid input field
                 * as defined in this function, and the main function */
                if (allGood && thisTag.value == "") {
                    classBack = "invalid "; /*Return class "invalid"*/
                }
                classBack += thisClass;
                /* `classBack` now holds "invalid reqd" or "reqd" */
                break;
            default:
                classBack += thisClass; /* Unknown class, ignore it */
        }
        return classBack; //Return the (altered) class
    }
}
```

Note: `allGood` is a variable defined in the main function(`validForm`):

```
function validForm() {
    var allGood = true;
    var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) { /*Walks through all elements*/
        if (!validTag(allTags[i])){ /*Checks whether an element is invalid or not*/
            allGood = false;
            /* `allGood` = false, notifies <function> allTags that an invalid
             * element has already been detected. */
        }
    }
   return allGood;

   ... //function validTag below
```

Your piece of code will validate elements, and focus at the first element which is invalid.

Comment: what is the significance of `thisTag.className = outClass;` this statement ?

Comment: The function's validation feature is heavily relying on the `class` attribute as a storage channel. E.g.: `class="foo bar reqd doo"`. When the input field is invalid, the class changes to `"foo bar reqd invalid"`. This change is saved using `thisTag.className = outClass;`.

Comment: i meant what is the need of this statement ? what does it do ? and then...when will the default case work in this script ?

Comment: That statement is overwriting the old `class` variable by the newer, possibly changed string of class names. What do you imply with "default case"?

Comment: i meant i don't see any case when the default case should work.Do you see any ?

Comment: Yes: Unknown class names are skipping `case "": case "invalid"`, `case "reqd"`. These class names are returned, so that the function does not remove possibly important class names.

Comment: and from where are the unknown class names generated ?

Comment: The developer of the webpage. Consider `class="shinyinpbox reqd"`.

Comment: ok..But i don't understand the need to dynamically change the class name of the element

Comment: Like I said, a few comments ago, the `class` attribute is used a storage and styling method: "reqd" is used to indicate that the element has to be validated, "invalid" is used to mark an invalid element.